# Units to use in Morse potential Equation

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am to graph the Energy potential curve (in $\text{cm}^{-1}$) for a molecule (HI),in the fundamental electronic state, according to the Morse oscillator. I believe I am to use this equation

$$E(R)=D_e\left[1-e^{-a(R-R_e)}\right]^2$$

However when I look at the units they don't seem to make sense to me. Parameters $a$ and $D_e$ should be $\text{cm}^{-1}$, so that the energy can be In $\text{cm}^{-1}$ as well. But that doesn't coincide with the formula given for the parameter $a$:
$$a=\left(\frac{\mu}{2D_e}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}2\pi\nu_e$$
I know $\mu$ has atomic mass units, and $D_e$ supposedly has $\text{cm}^{-1}$. $\nu_e$ should be Hertz. So the units really don't add up between equations, and I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Welcome on the Chemistry SE! I had happily converted your image into Latex formulas, but my eyes are not enough good for the task.

Comment: The exponential is dimensionless so $a$ has units m$^{-1}$ which it does as $D$ is an energy , joules, and $\nu$ a frequency, Hz, $a \equiv ( kg/(m^2 kg s^{-2}) )^{1/2}s^{-1} $. Convert $D_e$ from wave numbers into Joules and then plot $R$ in something like femtometers to get sensible numbers. You could plot $E/D_e$ vs $R$.